# printing output of lists:keysearch erlang

Tags: erlang

I am not able to print the return output of the following `lists:keysearch` function.

```
case lists:keysearch(Query,1,Data) of
    {value,Answer} ->
    io:format("~p",Answer);
    false ->
    io:format("not found ~n")
end,
```

I know Answer is my tuple that i should print out.Can anyone tell me what mistake i am doing ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`io:format` needs a *list* of arguments, even if there is only one:

```
io:format("~p", [Answer]);
```

Comment: +1 What's interesting is that he didn't get a badmatch (because Answer is a tuple and not a list).  That means keysearch always returns false.

Comment: @Narayanan Why don't you try running lists:keysearch for some values in the interpreter (erl)?  You might discover something interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to print the key that you found and thus do

```
{value, {Query, Answer}} -> io:format("~p", [Answer]);
```